# setDate not showing correct month - jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

setting default date does not showing the month I set, but the month +1

```
var defaultDateA1 = new Date(2014,7,1) 
$('#DRdatepicker').datepicker();
$('#DRdatepicker').datepicker('setDate', defaultDateA1);

//whole code below in not working as well
$( "#DRdatepicker" ).datepicker({
    readonly: true,
    //setDate: new Date(2014,7,1),  // First tried here, didn't work
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    autoSize: true
});
```

It is showing `08/01/2014`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

So you have to use

```
var defaultDateA1 = new Date(2014,7 - 1, 1)
```

With Date format:

```
$("#DRdatepicker").datepicker({
    readonly: true,    
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    autoSize: true
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date(2014, 7 - 1, 1));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/r2t0wu7v/)

Comment: Oops! Thanks, what about the code that is not working below, i.e dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to set date format as below :

```
 var defaultDateA1 = new Date(2014,7 - 1, 1) 
 var pickerOpts = {
            dateFormat:"y-mm-dd"

        };  
$('#DRdatepicker').datepicker(pickerOpts);  
$('#DRdatepicker').datepicker('setDate', defaultDateA1);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gktr6u8o/2/)